# can automatic background slideshow with fade effect be done with html and css only or we have to use JS and jQuery too?

Tags: html, css, background, slideshow, fade

I want to run an automatic background slideshow for my website with fade effect or any other similar to fade. tell me or add the code for automatic slideshow in my code. I tried many times but I am not able to run an slideshow.

that is what I want to do, so anyone help me please.

firstly try to make a automatic fade slideshow with css and html if it is impossible then use jQuery/JS

my html :

```css
body,
html {
 width: 100%;
 height: 100%;
 background-image: url(splash_image.jpg);
 background-size: cover;
}

* {
 overflow-x: hidden;
 font-family: "Raleway", sans-serif;
}

.logo {
 margin-top: 4%;
 font-size: 8vw;
 color: #3385ff;
}

.nav {
 list-style-type: none;
 padding: 0;
 background-color: #333;
 top: 0%;
 left: 0%;
 width: 100%;
 margin-top: 0%;
 margin-bottom: 0%;
 overflow: visible;
 position: absolute;
 width: 100%;
}

.nav a {
 float: left;
 display: block;
 color: #f2f2f2;
 text-align: center;
 padding: 14px 16px;
 text-decoration: none;
 font-size: 17px;
}

.active {
 background-color: #80e5ff;
 color: black !important;
}

.nav .icon {
 display: none;
}

.dropdown {
 float: left;
 overflow: hidden;
}

.dropdown .dropbtn {
 font-size: 17px;
 border: none;
 outline: none;
 color: white;
 padding: 14px 16px;
 background-color: inherit;
 font-family: inherit;
 margin: 0;
}

.dropdown-content {
 display: none;
 position: absolute;
 background-color: #f9f9f9;
 min-width: 160px;
 box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
 z-index: 1;
}

.dropdown-content a {
 float: none;
 color: black;
 padding: 12px 16px;
 text-decoration: none;
 display: block;
 text-align: left;
}

.nav a:hover:not(.active),
.dropdown:hover .dropbtn {
 background-color: #555;
 color: white;
}

.dropdown-content a:hover {
 background-color: #ddd;
 color: black;
}

.dropdown:hover .dropdown-content {
 display: block;
}

.logo-image {
 position: relative;
 animation-name: image;
 animation-duration: 2s;
 animation-delay: 3s;
 animation-fill-mode: both;
 margin-top: -4%;
}

@keyframes image {
 from {
  opacity: 0;
 }
 to {
  opacity: 1;
 }
}

#button {
 padding: 18px 36px;
 text-align: center;
 text-decoration: none;
 display: inline-block;
 font-size: 16px;
 margin-top: 4%;
 transition-duration: 0.4s;
 cursor: pointer;
 font-weight: 600;
 opacity: 0;
}

.button2 {
 background-color: transparent;
 color: white;
 border: 2px solid white;
}

.button2:hover {
 background-color: white;
 color: black;
 font-weight: 800;
}

#button-2nd {
 padding: 18px 36px;
 text-align: center;
 font-size: 16px;
 margin-top: 4px;
 margin-left: 50px;
 opacity: 0;
 transition: 0.3s;
 display: inline-block;
 text-decoration: none;
 cursor: pointer;
 font-weight: 600;
}

.button2-2nd {
 background-color: #3385ff;
 color: white;
 border: 2px solid #3385ff;
}

.button2-2nd:hover {
 opacity: 0.2;
 font-weight: 800;
}

.footer {
 position: fixed;
 left: 37%;
 bottom: 0;
 width: 25%;
 color: white;
 text-align: center;
 font-size: 16px;
}

.wrapper {
 text-align: center;
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 500px) {
 .logo {
  margin-top: 50px;
 }
 .logo-image {
  margin-top: 20px;
 }
 #button {
  padding: 6px 10px;
  margin-top: 100px;
 }
 #button-2nd {
  padding: 6px 10px;
 }
}

@media screen and (max-width: 500px) {
 .nav a:not(:first-child),
 .dropdown .dropbtn {
  display: none;
 }
 .nav a.icon {
  float: right;
  display: block;
 }
}

@media screen and (max-width: 500px) {
 .nav.responsive {
  position: absolute;
 }
 .nav.responsive .icon {
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
  top: 0;
 }
 .nav.responsive a {
  float: none;
  display: block;
  text-align: left;
 }
 .nav.responsive .dropdown {
  float: none;
 }
 .nav.responsive .dropdown-content {
  position: relative;
 }
 .nav.responsive .dropdown .dropbtn {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  text-align: left;
 }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
 <html>
 <head>

 <title>FosterX Gaming</title>

 <link rel="shortcut icon" type="image/png" href="logo.png">
 <script 
 src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"> 
</script>
 <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
 <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="FosterX.css">
 <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Raleway:200" 
 rel="stylesheet">
 </script>
 <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"> 
 </script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.0/umd/popper.min.js">

 </head>

 <body onload="typeWriter()">

 <div class="nav" id="Topnav">
 <a href="#" class="active">Home</a>
 <a href="#">Contact</a>
 <a href="#Login">Login</a>
 <div class="dropdown">
 <button class="dropbtn">Games 
  <i class="fa fa-caret-down"></i>
 </button>
 <div class="dropdown-content">
  <a href="#">PUBG</a>
  <a href="#">Fortnite</a>
  <a href="#">PUBG mobile</a>
</div>
</div> 
<a href="#about">About</a>
<a href="javascript:void(0);" style="font-size:15px;" class="icon" 
onclick="myFunction()">&#9776;</a>
</div>

<div class="wrapper">

<div class="logo" id="demo"></div>

 <img class="logo-image img-responsive" src="logo.png" alt="foster-logo" 
 height="30%" width="15%"><br><br>



<button class="button button2" id="button">Enter</button>
<button class="button-2nd button2-2nd" id="button-2nd">Leave</button>



<div class="footer">
<p>&reg; All Rights Reserved</p>
</div>
</div>

<script>
var i = 0;
var txt = '  FosterX Gaming';
var speed = 20;

function typeWriter() {
if (i < txt.length) {
document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML += txt.charAt(i);
i++;
setTimeout(typeWriter, 200);
}
}
</script>

<script>
$("#button").delay(3000).animate({"opacity": "1"}, 700)
</script>

<script>
$("#button-2nd").delay(3500).animate({"opacity": "1"}, 700)
</script>

<script>
function myFunction() {
var x = document.getElementById("Topnav");
if (x.className === "nav") {
    x.className += " responsive";
} else {
    x.className = "nav";
}
}
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: It is possible without using `js` look in to this [css animation](https://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/a/animation/) might be helpful

Comment: Who upvotes this craziness?